# Google Cloud ML - Can't Click the Start Training Button

Tags: training-data, google-cloud-ml

Guys

As Google Cloud ML request (AutoML Entity Extraction Project)

> Each label must have at least 50 annotations. Though ideally, each
> label should have at least 100 annotations. Fewer annotations often
> result in inaccurate precision and recall. You must also have at least
> 10 annotations each assigned to your Train, Validation and Test sets.

[More than 50 annotations, and at least 10 annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXSt.png)

But we still can't click the Start Training Button.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Extraction, AutoML requires at least 100 training items to be able to train your model as is mentioned in the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas#limits).

Here is a more detailed reference regarding Entity Extraction [2](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#expandable-2)

> You supply between 50 and 100,000 documents to use for training your
> custom model. You use between one and 100 unique labels to annotate
> the entities you want the model to learn to extract. Each annotation
> is a span of text and an associated label. Label names can be between
> 2 and 30 characters, and can be used to annotate between one and 10
> words. We recommend using each label at least 200 times in your
> training data set.

[image: 3]